# How to solve "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /boxed/index.html on this server."?

Tags: php, html

I have a folder in my web root (var/www/html), my folder is called "boxed".

If i put into this folder a .php file, and i go to localhost/boxed/myfile.php, it is loaded correctly and I see it in my browser.

But if I try to load an html file, I get "Forbidden" error of my question.

How can I solve this? Why php files work correctly but html files are denied?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Are you working in local? If yes, what is your operating system?

Comment: I'm working in local, using Lubuntu.

Comment: @sadrac This is not a programmatical question. Please ask this question in [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions. This link may be helpful for you to know about ubuntu file permissions